# SQL-Hi i wanted to put each alphabet of a sentence in each row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For example if the sentence is  "I am Good"

Identity    alphabet

1 i

2

3 a

4 m

5

6 g

7 o

8 o

9 d

Comment: What database are you using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Could you please try to write this *as a question*?

Comment: Do you want to put each character (not each "alphabet") of a string into a row of a table?

Comment: But why you want to store data like this?

Comment: Hi Nitin we are deidentifiying the data and then using cipher text to load it when it reaches the destination i will dencrypt the data.

Comment: Use Loop with Print that will do it!! but why use SQL for that!!?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following query:

```
DECLARE @R TABLE([INDEX] INT, Result CHAR(1))
DECLARE @T NVARCHAR(100) = 'I am Good'

DECLARE @Index INT = 1
WHILE (@Index <= LEN(@T)) BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @R( [INDEX], Result )
  VALUES  ( @Index,SUBSTRING(@T,@Index,1))
  SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @R
```

Comment: Hi Medhi, Thanks man it worked, i really do appericate your help!!!!